# raid 5 to raid 0

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, raid

So I have no clue about linux. I bought a server with 2x250gb SSD and 1x 2Tb HDD.

Are all my disk in a raid 5? does this even make sense to raid 5 two ssd and a hdd?

is it possible to raid 0 both ssd's and just mount the hdd from here?

I ran a few commands, I hope you can say how I can change it to raid 0 + 1 2tb hdd mount.

`df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  776K  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/md2        407G   23G  364G   6% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        487M   75M  387M  17% /boot
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
```

`lsblk`:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    16G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    16G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3    8:3    0 207.1G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 413.9G  0 raid5 /
sdb       8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sdb1    8:17   0    16G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    16G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3    8:19   0 207.1G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 413.9G  0 raid5 /
sdc       8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdc1    8:33   0    16G  0 part
│ └─md0   9:0    0    16G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdc2    8:34   0   512M  0 part
│ └─md1   9:1    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdc3    8:35   0 207.1G  0 part
  └─md2   9:2    0 413.9G  0 raid5 /
```

---

Edit: More informations:

`cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10]
md2 : active raid5 sdc3[3] sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      433990656 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 2/2 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      16759808 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]

md1 : active raid1 sdc2[2] sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      523264 blocks super 1.2 [3/3] [UUU]
```

Comment: run ``cat /proc/mdstat`` for more information. But as of right now it does look like the drives are split into three partitions with two of them being used in raid 1 (mirror) and 1 partition being used for raid 5.

Comment: Thats so strange. any idea how do change this that the two ssd's are in a raid 0 system and the hdd is just mounted for storage?

Comment: I'd rather keep that as a comment than a full answer: it seems you have a mix of partition recipes, that were thought to be multi purpose. If your server currently hold no important data, I would suggest to simply reinstall the OS and create your own raid 0 on SSD, and mount the hdd afterwards. This should be more simple to do than trying to use tools within the OS to change all current raids (mainly because your OS is also stored in one of storages).

Comment: Yeah i can reset the whole server. I think I will try that